# How to upload automatically in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to upload a file with a form but I can't fill the `<input type="file">` programmatically. Please show me a way to do this. it doesn't differ how. I just want to do that anyway.

Comment: You cannot set the file of a file input control programmatically. This is a security feature of the browser.

Comment: What can I do else? with other things except HTML?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, considering you could use it to steal people files o.O - that's a form of theft, you know =/

Comment: Sorry, it's just plain not possible. Imagine all the files I could steal from your PC if it was. The only way a file can be uploaded is if the user selects it.

Comment: What is your use case? Can synchronize files  to cloud storage services if that helps

Comment: I want to steal my own files :))
There is no way? with other programming languages?

Comment: Nothing in a browser is going to allow you to touch the user's filesystem progmatically without user input, if you want to upload your own files in bulk, then you'll need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a file to an input field because of security issues.

As a tip, if you wanted to suggest a file, but give them the opportunity to add one themselves, you could have something like this:

```
<input value="{{ my file name }}">

<label>Add your own file here:</label>
<input type="file">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer: you can't.** It's a security measure.

If file-inputs were writable I would be able to do something like this:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type="file";
input.value="Path/To/Your/Passwords";
myForm.appendChild(input);
myForm.submit();
```

And that's not wanted and so by default not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a file to input field because of security reason so you have to mention:

```
 <input type="file">

<input type="submit">
```